# cant get to upload url image from google Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

> I am trying to upload YouTube thumbnail to my cloud storage using
>   cloud function, the code runs fine in development mode but not when
>   deployed.

```
return bucket.upload('https://img.youtube.com/vi/dXo0LextZTU/0.jpg', options)
            .then(res => {

             console.log('uploaded');
            response.send(res);         })
.catch (err=>{
 response.send(err);
          });
```

> Is it just that i am using Free Plan? or some other issue with the code?

The error that appears in Deployment is
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND img.youtube.com:80`

Comment: What do the logs for your cloud function say?

Comment: error occured Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND img.youtube.com:80

Comment: I've been able to upload the file successfully using your code. Can you show the rest of your function's code in case there's something there?

Comment: it runs on localhost not on deployment in spark plan i guess

Comment: @abhishek Could you post the rest of your functions code? Sanitising any posible private information on it of course. I have also tried this and it works, so maybe something before is making it fail.

Comment: as i mentioned the problem is i am using  free plan, it works with paid plans and in development mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when deploying since the function is being executed while in Free Plan. It can only work with paid plans or in development.